# I have a problem with one of the exporting of excel/csv in symfony 2.8 application

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, utf-8

I have a problem with csv uploading in a symfony 2.8 application but it is only occurring in one client.

The log from CloudWatch:

> CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Your data could
>   not be encoded because it contains invalid UTF8 characters." at
>   /www/vendor/jms/serializer/src/JMS/Serializer/JsonSerializationVisitor.php.

Has anyone else encountered this? Help and tips would be highly appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: the exception message seems clear. what would you like from us?

Comment: I've checked the data from the db and I don't see any special character

Comment: Provide more details and share your code as well.